# Angularjs $timeout generating infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, timeout, settimeout

Hy
I have a div that simulates an input file button. 
To achieve this I did

```
angular.element('#fileInput').trigger('click');
```

but this generated an Apply already in progress error, googling around I found that this could easily be avoided putting the code inside a timeout.

```
timeOut = $timeout(function(){
        angular.element('#fileInput').trigger('click');
    });
```

And as an effect that really solved the problem, but $timeout generates an infinite loop opening infinite file dialogs if my pop-up block is disabled. In the AngularJS docs you can clearly read that $timeout is a wrapper of setTimeout wich should only generate one call to the callback function, so why is it generating an infinite loop? 
However, trying to solve the situtation I decided to kill the timer after the first call, but I couldn't manage,

```
timeOut = $timeout(function(){
    angular.element('#fileInput').trigger('click');
});
timeOut.then( function( ){$timeout.cancel(timeOut);
    }
);
```

I'm getting quite stuck in this situation... I'm I just missing something obvious things? Someone has any idea's? thank's

Comment: Are you sure that triggering the click doesn't somehow call this same code in return? Also, can you provide a jsFiddle or something, because I'm not sure I see how this behavior is happening

Comment: Not sure that I understood your question right, but yes, when I trigger the click it open's a file dialog, if he presses save then the upload is handled, otherwise nothing happens...I'll start working on the fiddle right now

Comment: My point was that I doubt the `$timeout` is the source of the problem (unless you're using a version of Angular that has a bug with it). I was suggesting that it's possible the code/function that contains this trigger is being called in recursion, causing the problem. I can't reproduce with a simple jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/twp3e6h2/), so you're going to need to, otherwise it doesn't make sense

Comment: Thank's for the help, couldn't manage to reproduce the error in a fiddle... quite wird! thank's anyway!

Comment: @Ian - I am pretty sure Ian is right. This happened to me recently, I used ng-click on a button to call a controller method which uses $timeout to trigger a click on a file input element, however the file input element is inside the button (hidden w/ display: none) that initiated ng-click, hence triggering an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why instead of using a $timeout you try to us an $interval and set it to run one time?

```
var interval =  $interval(function() {
    angular.element('#fileInput').trigger('click');
}, 100,1);
```